# Create a text file with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Given a string, how do I generate a .txt file containing such string?

Comment: Use `File.WriteAllText(filePath, StringToWrite);`

Comment: Ah! That is better. I would choose yours as answer =/

Comment: In that case, I've added it as an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx)

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, StringToWrite)
```